# Using PDFTextStream in Android, getting Java.awt.geom.generalpath (NoClassDefFound Exception)

Tags: java, android, pdf, awt

I'm trying to get pdf's to strings in my android app and using PDFTextStream to do so. However, I get the above exception when I try to do so.

I copied the code directly from the documentation: http://snowtide.com/help/extracting-text-from-pdf-documents

I am aware that Android does not support Java.awt. But is there any way to get this library to work on Android?

Full exception:

```
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
```

03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.GraphicsState.(SourceFile:40)
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.a.c.(SourceFile:75)
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.PDFTextStream.b(SourceFile:702)
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.PDFTextStream.a(SourceFile:687)
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.PDFTextStream.(SourceFile:572)
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.PDFTextStream.(SourceFile:600)
03-18 16:11:42.616: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.snowtide.pdf.PDFTextStream.(SourceFile:487)

Comment: `java.awt.geom` classes are part of the Java api, but they are not present on Android. If PDFTextStream requires them, you cannot simply use it on Android.

Comment: Any answer yet? 
Looking for the same.